# How to Preview a Form before submission in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, preview

Please, guys, I have this form which has three stages. 1. Fill Form. 2. Review Form 3. Confirm Form. I want it to be that whenever the user clicks next from the first stage it shows all the information the user has entered in the previous stage. Explained further with the images below.
[Fill Form Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIdk3.png)[Review Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmhZi.png)[Submission page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shsEa.png)

```html
Here's my HTML code
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- Start Page Content -->
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body wizard-content">
      <% if (locals.message) { %>
        <h4>
          <%= message %>
        </h4>
        <% } %>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle"></h6>
          <form id="example-form" action="/informationupdate" class="m-t-40" method="POST">
            <div>
              <h3>Account</h3>
              <section>
                <label for="date">Date *</label>
                <input id="date" name="date" type="date" class="required form-control">
                <label for="title">Title *</label>
                <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="required form-control">
                <label for="message">Message *</label>
                <input id="message" name="message" type="text" class="required form-control">
                <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
              </section>
              <h3>Review</h3>
              <section>
                <ul>
                  <li>Date</li>
                  <li>Bar</li>
                  <li>Foobar</li>
                </ul>
              </section>
              <h3>Finish</h3>
              <section>
                <input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required" a href="/informationupdate">
                <label for="acceptTerms">Check the box to successfully send your information.</label>
              </section>
            </div>
          </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ============================================================== -->
  <!-- End PAge Content -->

</div>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- End Container fluid  -->
```

```html
Here's my Javascript code for form submission
<script>
        // Basic Example with form
    var form = $("#example-form");
    form.validate({
        errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
        rules: {
            confirm: {
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        }
    });
     form.children("div").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return form.valid();
        },
        onFinishing: function(event, currentIndex) {
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
            return form.valid();
        },
        onFinished: function(event, currentIndex) {
            //form.submit().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
            form.submit().alert("submitted")
            //alert("Submitted!");
        }
    });


    </script>
```